# How can I insert a specific value from one multidimensional array into another?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Array A:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [project_id] => a
            [1] => a
            [title] => Yellow
            [2] => Yellow
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [project_id] => b
            [1] => b
            [title] => blue
            [2] => blue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [project_id] => c
            [1] => c
            [title] => green
            [2] => green
        )

)
```

Array B:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [project_id] => b
            [1] => b
            [name] => Ross
            [4] => Ross
            [15] => 
            [category] => horse
            [16] => horse
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [project_id] => b
            [1] => b
            [name] => Capone
            [4] => Capone
            [category] => cat
            [16] => cat
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [project_id] => c
            [1] => c
            [name] => Streisand
            [4] => Streisand
            [category] => elephant
            [16] => elephant
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [0] => 4
            [project_id] => a
            [1] => a
            [name] => Harper
            [4] => Harper
            [category] => frog
            [16] => frog
        )

)
```

I want to insert the values from `Array A` into `Array B` according to the project_id.

The result that I am trying to achieve is this:

Array C:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [project_id] => a
            [title] => Yellow
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [project_id] => b
            [title] => blue
            [horse] => Ross
            [cat] => Capone
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [project_id] => c
            [title] => green
            [elephant] => Streisand
            [frog] => Harper
        )

)
```

I am really lost, I tested working with array_merge, array_column and array_push. But I couldn't find the right method to solve this problem. Maybe it is not possible the way I want to do it? I am happy for any hint!

Comment: This is confusing. How is the merge supposed to work? You said you want to merge on `project_id`. But which `id` is supposed to be used then? In array A, there is one entry with `project_id = b` (it has `id = 2`), in array B there are two (one with `id = 1`, one with `id = 2`). You need to specify how this is supposed to happen exactly. Also, some of the values of the old arrays are supposed to become keys in the new array it seems? I'm talking about `cat` and `horse`. I'd say no library function will be able to do this for you. You'll need to write a custom merge method.

Comment: @domdom Hello. Well actually I thought that the project_id is the element to connect. So basically what I want is simple. If the project_id of both arrays match then I want to insert this the name from `$b` into the matching `$a`

Comment: The structure of Array `$a` keeps being the same. Also the id. I just insert for example an elephant and its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you want:

```
$arr1 = array
(
    0 => array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "0" => 1,
            "project_id" => "a",
            "1" => "a",
            "title" => "Yellow",
            "2" => "Yellow"
        ),

    "1" => array
        (
            "id" => 2,
            "0" => 2,
            "project_id" => "b",
            "1" => "b",
            "title" => "blue",
            "2" => "blue",
        )
,
    "2" => array
        (
            "id" => 3,
            "0" => 3,
            "project_id" => "c",
            "1" => "c",
            "title" => "green",
            "2" => "green"
        )

);
$arr2 =array
(
    "0" => array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "0" => 1,
            "project_id" => "b",
            "1" => "b",
            "name" => "Ross",
            "4" => "Ross",
            "15" => "",
            "category" => "horse",
            "16" => "horse",
        ),
        "1" => array
        (
            "id" => 2,
            "0" => 2,
            "project_id" => "b",
            "1" => "b",
            "name" => "Capone",
            "4" => "Capone",
            "category" => "cat",
            "16" => "cat",
        ),

    "2" => array
        (
            "id" => 3,
            "0" => 3,
            "project_id" => "c",
            "1" => "c",
            "name" => "Streisand",
            "4" => "Streisand",
            "category" => "elephant",
            "16" => "elephant"
        ),

    "3" => array
        (
            "id" => 4,
            "0" => 4,
            "project_id" => "a",
            "1" => "a",
            "name" => "Harper",
            "4" => "Harper",
            "category" => "frog",
            "16" => "frog"
        )

);

$new_arr=array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
  $new_arr_tmp=array();
  $new_arr_tmp["id"]=$value["id"];
  $new_arr_tmp["project_id"]=$value["project_id"];
  $new_arr_tmp["title"]=$value["title"];
  foreach ($arr2 as $key1 => $value1) {
    if($new_arr_tmp["project_id"] == $value1["project_id"])
    {
      $new_arr_tmp[$value1["category"]]=$value1["name"];
    }
  }

  $new_arr[]=$new_arr_tmp;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_arr);
```

demo:

https://eval.in/750450

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Just use two `foreach`.

```
<?php

$a = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            '0' => 1,
            'project_id' => 'a',
            '1' => 'a',
            'title' => 'Yellow',
            '2' => 'Yellow'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            '0' => 2,
            'project_id' => 'b',
            '1' => 'b',
            'title' => 'blue',
            '2' => 'blue'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3,
            '0' => 3,
            'project_id' => 'c',
            '1' => 'c',
            'title' => 'green',
            '2' => 'green'
        ]
];

$b = [
    [
            'id' => 1,
            '0' => 1,
            'project_id' => 'b',
            '1' => 'b',
            'name' => 'Ross',
            '4' => 'Ross',
            'category' => 'horse',
            '16' => 'horse'
    ],
    [
            'id' => 2,
            '0' => 2,
            'project_id' => 'b',
            '1' => 'b',
            'name' => 'Capone',
            '4' => 'Capone',
            'category' => 'cat',
            '16' => 'cat'
    ]
];

$final_array = [];

foreach($a as $item) {
    foreach($b as $item2) {
        if ($item['project_id'] == $item2['project_id']){
            $object = array_merge($item,$item2);
        } else {
            $object = $item;
        }
    }
    $final_array[] = $object;
}

var_dump($final_array);
```